# ASP.NET - Use a checkbox to change the results of a SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, parameters, checkbox, sqldatasource

I'm using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express. This is my first attempt at creating a .NET page. I have a Gridview on a page that displays the results of a GridQuery. This works. I have a checkbox control (cb_Filter) on the same page that if checked, should add to the where clause of the GridQuery, (where Column5 IS NULL). How do I check the state of the check box so it will run the query with or without the "filter".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

really depends on your data access, if you have made a datasource on page, then you'll have two and the code will change which data source you have. if it is using the old ado.net then you will have two commands that run in seperate methods that get the sql query, and a similar thing will work for linq. Let me know how you bind to the grid and i will give you an example.

Comment: Hopefully I'm understanding your question, I connect to the database using a "ConnectionString". I don't see any reference to ado.net so I assume it is the former.

Comment: @patrick in any case you need a connection string. Do you drop a datasource control on to the form? what does your code look like that gets your data into the grid?

Comment: <asp:SqlDataSource ID="GridQuery" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NGProdConnectionString %>" SelectCommand= "SELECT Column1, column2 FROM TABLE"> <FilterParameters> <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cb_Filter" Name="p_Filter" PropertyName="Checked" /> </FilterParameters> </asp:SqlDataSource>

Comment: ok so you have a datasource control. You need to create another of these, one with the where clause and one without and then in the code behind on the checkbox changed event(autopostback to true) give it a bit of if (check.Cheked) grid.datasource = datasource1; else grid.datasource = datasource 2

Comment: My GridView is called GridView1; its datasourceID = GridQuery1.  In which section does the conditional (if cb_filter.Checked THEN GridQuery1 ELSE GridQuery2) go?

Comment: in the code behind, you need to catch the checkchanged event of the check box. you do this by selecting it, going to properties-events(the lightning icon) then finding the event and double clicking on it to auto create the event(simplest way)

Comment: @patrick if you found the answer to this using my suggestion please mark it as answered. if not let me know where you are stuck. Thanks

Comment: I have created two SqlDataSources with slightly varied queries. The Checkbox now has autopostback back on and I entered the IF staments like this in the "CheckedChanged" event. I get the following error when I click the check box. "Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1' My event looks like this  Protected Sub cb_Filter_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles cb_Filter.CheckedChanged
        If cb_Filter.Checked Then GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource2 Else GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1
    End Sub

Comment: ok the thing to do really is to give the grids the datasource in design time, so keep the datasources on screen but don't have a datasource in the grid.datasource property, then you should be able to set it all at runtime

Answer (score 0):

If you want the grid results to change dynamically, autopostback should be True for the checkbox. This will cause the page to reload when the value changes. Then, in your page load routine you do something like this:

```
If cb_filter.Checked Then
   'set the checked datasource or SQL string here
Else
   'set the unchecked datasource or SQL string here
End If
```